# Undefined Tag in xml generated by MOXy

Tags: eclipselink, moxy

I have a JPA entity class with jpa annotations but without jaxb annotations:

```
@Entity
public class Category extends EntityObject {

    @Id
    private long id;

    // getter setter and stuff
}
```

Everything for jaxb is configured in an external xml file (because we need different serializations of the object).

```
<xml-bindings package-name="mystuff.category">
<java-types>
    <java-type name="mystuff.Category" xml-accessor-type="NONE">
        <xml-root-element name="category" />
        <java-attributes>
            <xml-attribute name="name" java-attribute="name" />
            <xml-element name="id2" java-attribute="id" />
        </java-attributes>
    </java-type>
// morestuff ...
```

my problems start when i marhall a category instance to xml. The result shows an additional id element that was not configured in the xml. and since category (or entityObject) doesn't have jaxb annotations i don't understand where it comes from.

```
<category xsi:type="category" name="Category_3">
    <id>1073741951</id>
    <id2>1073741951</id2>
</category>
```

when i explicitly add an xml-element entry for id to the moxy-xml i get an element that contains the id two times:

```
<id>10737419511073741951</id>
```

can somebody tell me how to get rid of this tag and were it comes from?

**EDIT**

Here the id related code in the EntityObject-Class

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class EntityObject implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public abstract long getId();

    @Field // a solr annotation
    public void setId(long id) {
        if (getId() <= 0) {
            setID(id);
        }
    }

    protected abstract void setID(long id);
```

Comment: What does EntityObject look like, does it contain an id property?  Which JPA implementation are you using?

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan added code for the EntityObject superclass.

Comment: Thanks for the update, I have added an answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/9741611/383861

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is due to the `id` property on `EntityObject` being overridden on the child object `Category`.

**Solution #1 - `EntityObject` and `Category` are in the same package**

Assuming that `EntityObject` is in the same package as `Category` you could do the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xml-bindings xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/oxm"
    package-name="mystuff.category">
    <xml-schema namespace="http://www.example.com/customer"
        element-form-default="QUALIFIED" />
    <java-types>
        <java-type name="EntityObject">
            <java-attributes>
                <xml-transient java-attribute="id" />
            </java-attributes>
        </java-type>
        <java-type name="Category" xml-accessor-type="NONE">
            <xml-root-element name="category" />
            <java-attributes>
                <xml-attribute name="name" java-attribute="name" />
                <xml-element name="id2" java-attribute="id" />
            </java-attributes>
        </java-type>
    </java-types>
</xml-bindings>
```

**Solution #2 - `EntityObject` and `Category` are in different packages**

If `EnityObject` and `Category` are in different packages you can create a second external mapping document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xml-bindings xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/oxm"
    package-name="another.pkg">
    <xml-schema namespace="http://www.example.com/customer"
        element-form-default="QUALIFIED" />
    <java-types>
        <java-type name="EntityObject">
            <java-attributes>
                <xml-transient java-attribute="id" />
            </java-attributes>
        </java-type>
    </java-types>
</xml-bindings>
```

Below is some sample code for bootstrapping from multiple external mapping documents:

```
package forum9724475;

import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.bind.*;    
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory;
import another.pkg.EntityObject;
import mystuff.category.Category;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>(1);
        List<String> oxm = new ArrayList<String>(2);
        oxm.add("mystuff/category/oxm.xml");
        oxm.add("another/pkg/oxm.xml");
        properties.put(JAXBContextFactory.ECLIPSELINK_OXM_XML_KEY, oxm);
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(new Class[] {Category.class}, properties);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

        Category category = new Category();
        category.setId(1073741951);
        marshaller.marshal(category, System.out);
    }

}
```

Below is the output from running the demo code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<category xmlns="http://www.example.com/customer">
   <id2>1073741951</id2>
</category>
```